# JSONata Transform Operator: Unexpected change in variable binding? between versions 1.8.6 and 2.0.3

Tags: node-red, jsonata

My business relies on the transform operator to manipulate prices according to the age of products, I therefore calculate an age for every product, then deduce its rebate rate and finally its new price. This has worked in the past (I THINK) by manipulating inventory with the transform operator together with inline variable assignments. Now by chance I came across a problem when I tried to use the chain operator together with inline variable assignments.

Long story, here's what I have narrowed the issue down to:

On https://try.jsonata.org/

set as data:

```
[
  {
    "a": 1
  },
  {
    "a": 2
  }
]
```

and as query:

```
$ ~> | $ | {
    "b": $c := a,
    "c": $c
} |
```

Now you get different answers depending on the JSONata version.

Up to 1.3.3, you get an error, THIS IS UNDERSTANDABLE.
From 1.4.1 to 1.8.6, you get this answer, which I expected:

```
[
  {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 1,
    "c": 1
  },
  {
    "a": 2,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 2
  }
]
```

BUT for version 2.0.3, you get an answer that frustrates me:

```
[
  {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 1
  },
  {
    "a": 2,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 1
  }
]
```

Why is that, and how can I find out, which JSONata my Nodered uses in its change nodes?

Thank you for any insight,
Sebastian

Comment: @hardillb Why was the `node-red` tag removed from this post? It appears that the OP has a legitimate question regarding it in the second part of his question.

Comment: Because the versions numbers mentioned don't match Node-RED version numbers, and the user has no control over jsonata versions, so this can't be about Node-RED

Comment: @hardillb Admittedly, I know nothing about Node-RED, but the JSONata version number the OP mentions in this post (1.8.6) appears to be [the version Node-RED uses in it's latest maintenance release](https://github.com/node-red/node-red/blob/master/package.json#L57C9-L57C27) (3.1.3). The 2.0.3 JSONata version is the latest version of JSONata which the exerciser defaults to (apparently not yet adopted by Node-RED). My assumption upon reading the OP's post is that they'd want to know which version of an expression to use for Node-RED, not necessarily how to change the version that Node-RED uses.

Comment: @OP That's an understandably frustrating bug in JSONata, apparently introduced by the Stedi team with their `async` changes for JSONata v2.0+ (most likely a missing `await` somewhere in their `apply()`/`evaluate()` changes). Looking at Node-RED's releases over the past 5 years using JSONata 1.8.X, this shouldn't affect you other then having to change the JSONata exerciser's version to match your Node-RED JSONata version, when testing your expressions. (Unless the Node-RED team eventually upgrades to a later version of JSONata before this is fixed in JSONata.)

Comment: Good catch, I've proposed a PR to fix this inconsistency: https://github.com/jsonata-js/jsonata/pull/665

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, all.
I was trying to find out if NodeRed somewhere tells me what version of jsonata was installed, or if I've missed a magic $version() function.

From Coleman's comment, I gather I'll better reformulate my business logic. I wander how many users will run into this problem when NodeRED bumps jsonata to 2.0.3.

Did I mention I love JSONata?